# Firebase Auth send verification email doesn't work on other devices

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase in my Angular app (Auth, Cloud Firestore & Storage). Now in my development computer everything works fine, sign up -> verification mail received -> login and so on... 
Another developer downloaded the zip from Github and everything still worked fine except the verification mail. He sign up with different users & never got the verification mail.

```
this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then((usr) => {
    console.log('signed up successfully');
    usr.user.sendEmailVerification()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Verification email was sent');
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('Verification email failed');
      });
```

This code work every time in my personal computer & never worked in other... Am I missing something? Is it somehow related to the project settings on Firebase Console?

Comment: what is the value of usr?

Comment: Thanks for your response!  
additionalUserInfo: Mf {providerId: "password", isNewUser: true}
credential: null
operationType: "signIn"
user: {
uid: "...",
email: ".."
emailIsVerified: 
}
and so on

Comment: I will remote control the other computer and see the log

Comment: If the same code worked for you, but doesn't work on another machine, the problem is not likely to be in that code. Have the other developer check their spam box, as it's most likely that the message was blocked somewhere along the way to them.